# G. P. Thomson writes in his paper that there is 5% unexplained error in de-broglie wavelength at non-relativistic velocity, has it been explained?

Tags: particle-physics, wave-particle-duality, wavelength

Here [is the link to the 1927 paper:](https://www.plasma.uaic.ro/topala/articole/GP%20Thomson%201928.pdf)

"It should be emphasised that there are no adjustable constants;
the agreement is direct except for a 5 per cent. error. It is an important
question whether this error is an experimental one in the measurement of the
speed of the rays, as suggested above, or whether it represents some correction
on the simple theory.
*It may be remarked that Davissons and Germers' results appear to show an error of about the same magnitude in the same direction."

Comment: Can you link to the paper? If it's one of the classics from the early days of quantum mechanics, 5% may well lie within the experimental uncertainty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old paper and even the author himself in comparing the experiment to the calculations doubts the discrepancy:

> The 
>   measurement 
>   of 
>   energy 
>   by 
>   spark 
>   gap 
>   is 
>   not 
>   a  very 
>   satisfactory 
>   method, 
>   especially 
>   when 
>   a rapidly 
>   alternating 
>   potential 
>   like 
>   that 
>   of 
>   an 
>   induction 
>   coil 
>   is 
>   used. 
>   and 
>   there 
>   may 
>   quite 
>   possibly 
>   be 
>   a  systematic 
>   error 
>   due 
>   to 
>   this. 
>   On 
>   the 
>   other 
>   hand 
>   there 
>   may 
>   be 
>   some 
>   correction 
>   required 
>   in 
>   the 
>   theory

Since the de Broglie wavelength experiments have had almost a 100 years of finding a real discrepancy, it is not worth checking the systematics of this old one .

Comment: I am sorry but i have come up with a different theory for producing undulatory motion for electrons and there is a consistent 5.599% Smaller wavelength than de-broglie for the the same frequency E/h.

Comment: this is not the site for new theories.  If you have done the experiment and can demonstrate a statistically significant discrepancy you should submit the results to be peer reviewed and published. The same if you have a new theory, then you should ask for a modern test of the theory, not base it on possible systematic errors of 90 years ago. again, this is not the site for new theories.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comment. I have a simulation result but no physically performed experiment.